# Speed up Mysql UPDATE when joining a table with LIKE

Tags: mysql

Below is my query

```
UPDATE cdata AS gcd 
LEFT JOIN tar AS ap 
ON gcd.dialled
LIKE CONCAT(ap.prefix, '%')
SET gcd.prefix=ap.prefix, gcd.destination1=ap.destination
WHERE gcd.prefix=0;
```

This seems to timeout and I was wondering if it is the LIKE that is doing it. cdata has about 140000 records and its searching against tar which has around 25000. So I guess mysql is doing 25000 lookups for each of the 140000 records?

I need to find a way to speed it up if possible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: is there an index on gcd.dialled?

Comment: You can ask MySql to EXPLAIN how it will execute your query - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Yes there is an index on dialled and prefix

Comment: EXPLAIN on UPDATE is not available on my version I dont think

Comment: really, no explain on UPDATE?  You could do explain on the equivalent select...

Comment: I would investigate what happens if you run it as a select instead...do you get multiple matches for some rows?  If you are over-writing the same row multiple times it could make it slow

Comment: If the prefix is 3-4 chars fixed, wouldn't `SUBSTRING(gcd.dialed, 1, 4) = ap.prefix` be a lot faster?  Might at least take advantage of one index that way.  (I'm assuming prefix is UNIQUE in tar...)

Comment: Unfortunately the prefix ranges from 3-9

Comment: In the absence of a NULL condition, I imagine OUTER JOINs in UPDATE queries must be vanishingly rare.

Comment: @Strawberry, especially when the WHERE clause restricts to non-null values in the outer table.  This is a case of someone using a LEFT JOIN without understanding what it means.

Comment: You're right I don't, forgive my ignorance... Trying to learn though! I do find the mysql docs a bit of a minefield!

Comment: This is a useful explanation: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, should be a better way, maybe with `UNION`?  Break it into 7 queries, 1 for each length of ap.prefix that is possible:

```
UPDATE cdata AS gcd
JOIN tar AS ap
ON substring(gcd.dialled, 1, 3) = ap.prefix
SET gcd.prefix=ap.prefix, gcd.destination1=ap.destination
WHERE gcd.prefix=0
;
-- ...
UPDATE cdata AS gcd
JOIN tar AS ap
ON substring(gcd.dialled, 1, 9) = ap.prefix
SET gcd.prefix=ap.prefix, gcd.destination1=ap.destination
WHERE gcd.prefix=0
;
```

Run all of the queries and it should update all of your data in a reasonable time.  (Note: I switched to `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` to avoid putting `NULL` into rows that were previously 0).

Comment: Thats interesting, thank you! Could I run this in one query from PHP?

Comment: This worked perfectly and completed in seconds! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @jhodgson4 I managed a `UNION` version.  However it's slower and very ugly.  I tried `IN` statements and `OR` statements but couldn't get the optimization right for some reason (they were so slow they didn't run).

Answer (score 0):

This approach is wrong. You should never use `UPDATE` queries on indefinite data.

Comment: So what approach should I take?